# Connect react is components visually by lines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I am building an app using reactjs for the frontend. The components are dragged by the user and added on the screen. After displaying the items I want to give the user ability to draw lines between the components.

I would like to visually show the relationship between two react components.  Like an Entity Relationship Diagram but these can be arbitrary components. I can't seem to find best solution for the problem. lineto and other solutions don't work between components. It should be able to draw the line by clicking the two components by dragging a line.

**Adding more detail for clarification**